# how to convert integer to logical array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert a number(eg:`3`) to it's logical array(`[0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]`).
In matlab, we can use

```
a = 1:10
b = 3
a == b
```

then, we can get   `0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0`. 
How can I get it in python, because when I try this in python, I got:

```
In [220]: import numpy as np

In [221]: a = np.arange(10)

In [222]: b = 3

In [223]: a == b
Out[223]: array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: In MATLAB, that logical array is represented as 0s and 1s, whereas in Python/NumPy, those are given True and False for representation. People might suggest you to use type conversion to int dtype, but that's no longer a boolean/logical array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert it to an integer afterwards:

```
(a == b).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you ant the same output as `MATLAB`, you need

```
np.asarray(a + 1 == b).astype(np.int32)
```

or to define `a` as

```
a = np.arange(1,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `a == b` by `np.array(a == b).astype(np.int32)`
By changing the type it will solve your problem.

Comment: You are so quick!

Comment: You could use `np.asarray` instead of `np.array` to avoid a copy.